# Ajax div can't access address bar variable

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, address-bar

Can someone please advise me on how my Ajax div can get an address bar variable. The usual way just doesn't work.

My address bar currently looks like this:

```
http://localhost/social3/browse/?locationName=Cambridge
```

Obviously, the word I'm trying to access here is 'Cambridge'. Usually, I would use a little php and do this:

```
$searchResult = $_POST['locationName'];
echo $searchResult;
```

But because I'm in an Ajax div, I can't seem to get to the variable.

Do I need to add some JavaScript wizardry to my Ajax coding? (I have little knowledge of this)

My Ajax:

```
<script>    
window.onload = function () {
    var everyone = document.getElementById('everyone'),
        searching = document.getElementById('searching'),
        searchingSubmit = document.getElementById('searchingSubmit');

    everyone.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexEveryone');
        everyone.className = 'filterOptionActive';
        searching.className = 'filterOption';
    }

    searching.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexSearching');        
        searching.className = 'filterOptionActive';
        everyone.className = 'filterOption';
    }

     searchingSubmit.onclick = function() {
        loadXMLDoc('indexSearchingSubmit');  
    }

    function loadXMLDoc(pageName)
    {
        var xmlhttp;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
          {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
          xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
          }
        else
          {// code for IE6, IE5
          xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
          {
          if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
            document.getElementById("leftCont").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
          }

        function get_query(){
          var url = location.href;
          var qs = url.substring(url.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
          for(var i = 0, result = {}; i < qs.length; i++){
            qs[i] = qs[i].split('=');
            result[qs[i][0]] = decodeURIComponent(qs[i][1]);
          }
          return result;
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET","../browse/" + pageName + ".php?user=" + get_query()['user'],true);
        xmlhttp.send();
        }
}
</script>
<!-- ends ajax script -->
```

Comment: Getting a what from a what now? It's not an adressbar variable, it's a POST or GET variable, gotten from a form submit or pageload that submits those values to the serverside, so without reloading the page, you'd get the current URL with `window.location`, and the search parameters with `window.location.search` ?

Comment: Hi, I've not had a thorough look through your sample code, but I'd suggest Googling something like: JavaScript parse query string url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your url contains the variable, you should use `$_GET["key"]` instead of `$_POST`

alternatively, you can use `$_REQUEST["key"]` to handle both cases.